# mysql query to get the average from the latest N rows for distinct phone_numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

My table is (phone_number, bpm, timestamp). I want to get the phone_number, avg(bpm) for the latest 10 rows for each phone_number. I have tried..

```
SELECT phone_number, AVG( bpm ) 
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE bpm !=0
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
) AS temp
GROUP BY phone_number
HAVING COUNT( * ) <=10
```

This query is giving empty result. I cannot use IN clause in my version of mysql.

Comment: `I cannot use IN clause in my version of mysql.` Please elaborate.

Comment: I am using mysql 5.5 and get this error on using IN clause in my queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pain in MySQL.  The most reasonable solution uses variables to enumerate the rows and then aggregation:

```
SELECT phone_number, AVG(bpm)
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (@rn := if(@pn = phone_number, @rn + 1,
                        if(@pn := phone_number, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM table_name t CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT @pn := '', @rn := 0) params
      WHERE bpm <> 0
      ORDER BY phone_number, timestamp DESC
     ) t
WHERE rn <= 10
GROUP BY phone_number;
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I do not understand these parts, 
`(@rn := if(@pn = phone_number, @rn + 1,
                        if(@pn := phone_number, 1, 1)
                       )
             )`
and `SELECT @pn := '', @rn := 0`
Can you please explain?

Comment: @HarishVishwakarma . . . Look up user variables in the MySQL documentation.  These are user variables that are implementing the equivalent of the ANSI standard `row_number()` function.